# quirks in Lubuntu

Tags: kernel

I need to edit loader.conf in Lubuntu but `find / -name loader.conf` doesn't return anything.

The file I'm looking for is supposed to be inside of `/boot/loader` but this folder doesn't exist.

The point is setting what is call a "quirk" as a kernel option.

NOTE: On some baytrail intel atom laptops, sound simply doesn't work and you have to pass `snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640.quirk=0x502f30` as a kernel option (from [this post](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211485))

Comment: Where do you get 'loader.conf' from?  If youi're trying to set a kernel option you would set that in the grub command line and then update-grub.  And what do you mean by "quirks"?

Comment: @ThomasWard at least [here's some information about quirks](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/writing_musb_glue_layer/device-quirks.html), but OP's not giving much detail of what they is referring to.

Comment: I edited the post so as readers will see the point

Comment: @ThomasWard, yes I need to pass this option to grub cmd line but how ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter

Comment: @Yvain so, you have your answers there on what to edit?

Comment: Yes thank you !